# write dbf slice from dbf in python

Tags: python, database, foxpro, dbf

I would like to use the [DBF](http://pythonhosted.org/dbf/) module to split a vfp dbf based on a value in a column, **dist**. I therefore extracted all necessary indices to use them for the export. Unfortunately, the original table does not allow a list of indices.

```
input_file = 'refrence.dbf'

table = dbf.Table(input_file)
l = []

for ind, record in enumerate(table.open(mode=dbf.READ_WRITE)):
    with record as r:
        if r.dist >= start and r.dist <= end:
            l.append(ind)
```

is there an easier way to get to *n* separate dbf files containing only the rows which satisfy the condition *`r.dist >= start and r.dist <= end`* ?

Comment: What do you find hard about the solution you got?

Comment: I get the following error: `TypeError: type <<type 'list'>> not valid for indexing` when trying to access `table[l]`

Comment: I also don't know how to export the `table[l]` to the another vfp dbf. The documentation is very basic.

Answer (score 1):

I would try something like the following (untested):

```
def copy_range(source, destination, field_name, start, end):
    src = dbf.Table(source).open()
    dst = src.new(destination).open(dbf.READ_WRITE)  # copy structure
    for record in src:
        if start <= record[field_name] <= end:
            dst.append(record)
    src.close()
    dst.close()
```

Then call it like:

```
copy_range('refrence.dbf', 'result.dbf', 'dist', 100, 200)
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. I think you have to change `table` to `src` in the for loop. Because there is no `table` in your code. I also get the following error: `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'inar' ` which I think is related to the data inside the **dbf**.  Is there an option to allow strings and double in the same dbf?

Comment: I posted a traceback in the other answer to the question.It is almost the same that I got from executing your code.

Comment: Well, @F.Motz, Ethan Furman is the author of the dbf module so listen to the man! :-)

Answer (score 1):

Selecting the records can be done by:

```
target_records = [rec for rec in table if start <= rec.dist <= end]
```

Once you have the records, it's fairly easy to copy them into a new dbf:

```
new_table = old_table.new('some_file.dbf')
with new_table:
    for record in target_records:
        new_table.append(record)
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I tried your code but got the following error: `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'inar' ` which I think is related to the data inside the dbf. Is there an option to allow strings and double in the same dbf?
(same comment as above)

Comment: `[...]

  File "xxx\dbf\ver_2.py", line 5404, in new
    return Table(filename, field_specs, memo_size, ignore_memos, codepage, default_data_types, field_data_types, dbf_type=self._versionabbr, on_disk=on_disk)

  File "xxx\dbf\ver_2.py", line 4785, in __init__
    self.add_fields(field_specs)

  File "xxx\dbf\ver_2.py", line 5057, in add_fields
    length, decimals, flags = init(pieces, flags)

  File "xxx\dbf\ver_2.py", line 3898, in add_vfp_double
    decimals = int(format[0][1:-1]) if len(format) else 0

ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'inar'`

Comment: @F.Motz: Try installing the latest version of `dbf`:  `pip install dbf --upgrade`; I don't think it will help, but it's good to have the latest version.  It looks like your dbf may be corrupted.  Feel free to email me and I can take a look at it.

Comment: I updated my dbf module but got the same error. Sent an email to ethanf@admailinc.com and got an error as well :) whats your current mail address?

Comment: @F.Motz: It's at the top of the `__init__.py` file in the dbf folder (sorry, I get enough spam as it is).

Comment: Looks like the above error is a bug in `dbf`; working on a fix.

Answer (score 1):

You can access filtered table like this

```
table[l]["dist"]
```

or

```
table[l][fieldName]
```

or

```
table[l][0]
```

You should make your dbf file with this filtered data.